# is a c++ array of size N a distinct type

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

I thought that

```
int a1[5];
```

and

```
int a2[6];
```

were distinct types.

But

```
void foo(int a[5]){};
void foo(int a[6]){};
```

will not compile saying that they are duplicated definitions of foo (ie `foo(int *a)`)

I was very surprised by this. One of the reasons I saw given for why VLAs are not allowed in the c++ standard is because they break the type system.

I was also surprised to find c doing the same thing.

```
void foo(int a[4]){
   printf("sz=%ld", sizeof(a));
}
```

reports a pointer size. I expected it to report `4*sizeof(int)` (and only accept a variable of type `int[4]` to be accepted as a call argument)

Comment: I'd have to verify, but I think you are just running into plain old *array-pointer* conversion.

Comment: Well, yeah. `a` is a pointer. Arrays in arguments are just pointers. This is the case both in C and in C++.

Comment: in C/C++ when you pass an array to a function you only get a pointer to the 0th index of the array there is no way around it that is the reason many functions in C/C++ take an array and a sizeof array on each call you may want to watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaclhRKfxtI

Comment: @pm100, `int a[5]` as a function parameter is the same type as `int *a`.  So is `int a[6]`.  It is not an array to pointer to first element issue, but a language issue concerning function declarations.

Comment: If you want an actual array, you have to pass it by reference (`void foo(int (&a)[5]){}`)

Comment: @pm100 `printf("sz=%ld", sizeof(a));` better as `printf("sz=%zu", sizeof(a));` to avoid sidebar issues of using the wrong specifier.

Comment: i guess this one of the reasons for std::array, different sizes are distinct types.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel - OK I now get that declaring a function arg as `int[5]` is the same as `int *` (which is a surprise to me). But are `int[5]` and `int[6]` distonct in other ways

Comment: @pm100   Yes.  Function arguments are special - in both C and C++  (some might say an anomaly of the language, but that's how it is).  There are other contexts in which `int[5]` and `int [6]` are different types.  e.g.  `int x[5]; int (&r)[5] = x; int (*p)[5] = &x;` is valid (and defines `r` and `p`, respectively, as a reference and a pointer to an array of 5 `int`) but  `int x[6]; int (&r)[5] = x; int (*p)[5] = &x` has two diagnosable errors (since neither a reference nor a pointer to an array of 5 elements can refer/point to an array with 6 elements).

Comment: Types `int[5]` and `int[6]` are distinct while due to array decay types `void(int[5])`, `void(int[6])` and `void(int*)` are the same

Comment: The thing that is confusing you is that you can't have an argument with an array type -- it will always be converted into a pointer to the array's element type, to match up with the pointer type an array will automatically get converted to when you try to use it as an argument in a call.

Comment: Avoid the problem entirely by just forgetting C-style arrays exist and use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they are distinct types, this can be confirmed with:

```cpp
int a[5];
int b[6];
static_assert(!std::is_same_v<decltype(a), decltype(b)>);
```

Your problem is that in function parameter lists, arrays are silently replaced with pointers, so both `void foo(int a[5])` and `void foo(int a[6])` end up as `void foo(int *a)`.

This (replacing array type with pointer) only happens to actual arrays, as opposed to e.g. references to arrays, so `void foo(int (&a)[5])` would work (or `int (*a)[5]` in C).

Comment: are they distinct in c, is there a way to show this?

Comment: @pm100 the `sizeof` will be different which AFAIK means they cant be the same type.

Comment: @pm100   `int x[5]; int (*p)[6] = &x`  will not compile, since `x` is an array of five elements, and `p` is a pointer to an array of 6 elements.   This is true in both C and C++.     Also, `sizeof(int [5])` and `sizeof(int[6]`) will produce different values in both languages (and `sizeof(int *)` is another value, which will probably not be equal to either)

Comment: Function types are similarly replaced with pointers when you use them as argument types in a declaration, so it is not *just* array types.

Comment: A curiosity on this topic is that an array object may be of a different _declared_ type at one point, in say one translation unit (TU; at which point its type is incomplete) and in another translation unit be complete of and a different declared type, meaning `int a[]` in TU #1 is of a different type than `int a[5]` in TU #2. Adding another definition of `int a[7]` in TU #3 is UB via ODR-violation. Array objects are one of [the few entities that may have different types in different contexts](https://dfrib.github.io/same-entity-different-type/).

Comment: Re “This only happens to arrays”: I think you mean this happens to parameters that are directly declared as arrays and not to arrays nested within a parameter declaration. However, as stated, it does not happen only to arrays. A parameter declared as a function will also be adjusted to be a parameter that is a pointer to a function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil By "this" I meant replacing an array with a pointer. Should sound better now.